# What is the package name for Software & Updates and how to remove it?

Tags: 16.04, updates, uninstall

I think command line `apt update` is quite enough, so I want to remove the package for Software & Updates, however I don't know its name.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The package is called `software-properties-gtk`.

I do not recommend removing it. It will remove `ubuntu-desktop`. I see no reason why remove this package even if you do not use it.

Comment: That's a dangerous move... Thanks for reminding..

Comment: `ubuntu-desktop` is *probably* only an empty package that depends on all the various desktop components, so that installing `ubuntu-desktop` installs those components. If that's the case removing it won't break anything. I don't know how to check that though.

Comment: @immibis That is true. But still, I do not recommend to remove base Ubuntu packages. Something else may depend on it.It is not worth the effort to check.

Comment: `apturl`, `nautilus-share` depends on it too. removing it causing those to be removed